# How to call .CS WebService to javascript for android?

Tags: android, web-services

I have a wsdl service and as i generate it with svcutil.exe, it gave me a .cs file. Now my question is how can I call the service with javascript for android. where do I go from here? any suggestions or any reference/step-by-step tutorial or a sample demo would be a great help for me. I am developing an application for android with phonegap 1.4.1, Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial describe how to call a webservice directly from javascript:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/