# WSDL webservice to javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, wsdl

> > You have created a service.
> >
> > To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:
> >
> > svcutil.exe https://test-services.com/Service.svc?wsdl
> >
> > This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service.

-Guys i am new with webservices. and i am developing android application with phonegap. can you please help me on how to call this service? with javascript? thank you guys. i already have generated the files with scvutil.exe and now i have this .cs and output.config files, and i dont know what to do next? tried googling but everything seems to be a little bit confusing for me. can you please guide me through this? thank you so much. please help me.

Comment: Let's see if I got this straight. You generated a WCF web service and now you want to call it with javascript?

Comment: im not exaclty sure if its a WCF or not. my boss just gave me the service address link. and as i open it in my broswer. it gives me the message that i posted above. so i generated the service address via svcutil.exe, and so i now have two files that was generated. which is the .cs file and output.config.

Comment: That is a standard message for dot.NET web services and those files are dot.NET files (most likely in C# if you didn't add parameters to svcutil.exe). You can't use those files to call the web service from javascript. You can use those files only in a dot.NET (C# likely) client.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622202/how-to-call-cs-webservice-to-javascript-for-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest SOAP example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example)